# PVC is in terminating state and PV is in bound state in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, openshift

I have the PVC which is in terminating state (because it is referenced from 3 other pods) and the PV is in bound state. PV has the retain reclaiming policy.

Also I am not sure on the reason for the PVC getting terminated, there is no events available.

May I know the steps to restore / recover the PVC back to bound state? If you could provide the steps it would be very helpful.